# Способы последовательной инициализации элементов массива

Tags: c, массивы, инициализация

Есть ли разница между двумя фрагментами по производительности, использованию памяти, иной пользе?

```
int argc;
char *argv[4];
argc = 0;
argv[argc++] = "UNZIP";
argv[argc++] = "-o";
argv[argc++] = "-qq";
argv[argc++] = "abc.zip";
```

---

```
char *argv[4];
argv[0] = "UNZIP";
argv[1] = "-o";
argv[2] = "-qq";
argv[3] = "abc.zip";
```

Comment: Лучше откомпилить оба варианта с разными ключами оптимизации и посмотреть получающийся ассемблерный код. Вообще, если оптимизатор не очень умный, то на второй вариант он сгенерит последовательное присвоение четырех адресов, а для первого случая заведет переменную, будет ее увеличивать и последовательно заносить адреса, что вероятно медленнее. Но современные компиляторы очень умные и при определенных ключах оптимизации вполне могут для обоих случаев сгенерить одинаковый код

Comment: Даже если и есть, попробуйте оценить эту самую разницу. 4 байта памяти и три наносекунды скорости?

Comment: современные компиляторы достаточно умные, что бы догадаться, что в первом случае программист просто поленился вписать индексы ручками и сделают рассчеты сами. То есть, разница в скорости исполнения вряд ли какая то будет. А вот в скорости компиляции будет отличаться. Но что бы ее почувствовать, нужно будет много подобного кода написать.

Comment: На мой взгляд в ситуациях, когда все известно на момент компиляции, правильнее инициализировать массив литералов по месту. Вариант с инкрементом может быть актуален, если есть ветвления по коду.

Comment: @alexolut Или если строк очень много, напряжно будет эти индексы вбивать, и еще местами их менять тоже не удобно будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с того, что эти два варианта семантически разные.

В первом варианте создаются две переменные, `argc` и `argv`, которым присваиваются значения.

```
int argc;
char *argv[4];
argc = 0;
argv[argc++] = "UNZIP";
argv[argc++] = "-o";
argv[argc++] = "-qq";
argv[argc++] = "abc.zip";
```

Если массив будет объявлен со значительно большим числом элементов, то такой подход не рационален, так как программа будет забита предложениями присваивания. Проще было бы записать

```
char *argv[] = 
{
    "UNZIP", "-o", "-qq", "abc.zip",
};

int argc = ( int )( izeof( argv ) / sizeof( *argv ) );
```

Если эти переменные моделируют параметры командной строки, которые передаются функции main, то нужно будет добавить еще один элемент в массив `argv`, который равен `NULL`.

```
char *argv[] = 
{
    "UNZIP", "-o", "-qq", "abc.zip", NULL
};

int argc = ( int )( izeof( argv ) / sizeof( *argv ) ) - 1;
```

В этом случае `argv[argc]` будет равно `NULL`. То есть для параметров командной строки длина массива задается на единицу меньше, чем реальное число элементов в массиве.

Если имеет место ситуация, когда вы не можете инициализировать массив при его объявлении, то, опять-таки, подход зависит от того, нужна ли вам переменная `argc`, или требуется только заполнить сам массив.

Использование переменной `argc` делает код более гибким, так как в случае редактирования строк с присваиванием, вам не потребуется изменять индексы элементов в случае, когда новый элемент добавляется или удаляется из середины массива.

Answer (score 4):

Оптимальный способ инициализации будет вот такой:

```
char *argv[] = {"UNZIP", "-o", "-qq", "abc.zip"};
```

Во-первых, это читается легче, во-вторых, вы не запутаетесь с индексами элементов при изменении количества элементов, ну и в третьих, ассемблерный код получается очень лаконичным:

```
0x4017c2    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x18],0x404089
0x4017ca    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x40408f
0x4017d2    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x20],0x404092
0x4017da    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x24],0x404096
```

Число элементов в массиве можно получить вот так:

```
int argc = sizeof argv / sizeof(argv[0]);
```

При этом, в рантайме, никаких реальных вычислений производиться не будет. Всё вырождается в:

```
0x4017e2    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x2c],0x4
```

Answer (score 3):

Разница, если и будет, то в пределах погрешности измерений. а вот поддерживать первый вариант легче на порядок. Когда Вы решите добавит или удалить параметр из середины массива